# Tinymce doesn't generate pre-signed urls for uploaded images

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, tinymce, pre-signed-url

I am developing a Django blog application where I utilize Tinymce as the text editor for the content of the posts. To store the uploaded images, I use AWS S3. The problem is that Tinymce does not generate pre-signed URLs for the uploaded images, leading to access denied errors when the expiration time is reached.

This is the error I get:

> `AccessDenied` Request has
> expired 3600
> 2023-06-07T03:26:09Z
> 2023-06-07T15:46:49Z
> xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx

When an image is uploaded through Tinymce, it is stored as a link in the text area. However, Tinymce does not generate new pre-signed URLs for the images when a post is opened, resulting in the images retaining the same URL that was initially generated during the post's save operation.

Since the pre-signed URLs for the Tinymce images do not change, when the expiration time set for the URLs is reached, the images become inaccessible, and I encounter an "access denied" error.

I have other images in the blog that are served fine. The problem is just happening with those uploaded in Tinymce

These are some relevant code snippets:

uploadfile.js

```
const image_upload_handler_callback = (blobInfo, success, failure, progress) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.withCredentials = false;
    xhr.open('POST', '/' + userLanguage + '/upload_image/');

    xhr.upload.onprogress = (e) => {
        progress(e.loaded / e.total * 100);
    };
    
    xhr.onload = () => {
        if (xhr.status === 403) {
            failure('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status);
            return;
        }
      
        if (xhr.status < 200 || xhr.status >= 300) {
            failure('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status);
            return;
        }
      
        const json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      
        if (!json || typeof json.file_path != 'string') {
            failure('Invalid JSON: ' + xhr.responseText);
            return;
        }
      
        success(json.file_path);
    };
    
    xhr.onerror = () => {
      failure('Image upload failed due to a XHR Transport error. Code: ' + xhr.status);
    };
    
    const formData = new FormData();
    const csrftoken = document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value;
    formData.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', csrftoken); // Add CSRF token to form data
    formData.append('image', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());
    
    xhr.send(formData);
};

tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    plugins: 'image textcolor',
    toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | image',
    images_upload_handler: image_upload_handler_callback,
});
```

settings.py

```
# AWS
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = config('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = config('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = config('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')

AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'us-east-1'
AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = 's3v4'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

THUMBNAIL_DEFAULT_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
```

views.py

```
class TinymceS3Storage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = 'media/uploads/tinymce/images'
    file_overwrite = False  # Optional: Set to True if you want to overwrite existing files

    def get_default_headers(self, *args, **kwargs):
        headers = super().get_default_headers(*args, **kwargs)
        headers['Cache-Control'] = 'public, max-age=31536000'
        return headers

def upload_image(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        image = request.FILES.get('image')

        # Generate a unique filename for the image
        filename = f"{uuid.uuid4().hex}{image.name.split('.')[-1]}"

        # Save the image to S3
        storage = TinymceS3Storage()
        image_path = storage.save(filename, image)

        # Construct the public URL for the uploaded image
        image_url = storage.url(image_path)

        # Return the image URL as a JSON response
        return JsonResponse({'file_path': image_url})

    else:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Invalid request method'})
```

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on this a whole day, and the solution looks quite simple now. Just creating the regular url, without the presigned elements.

```
image_url = f"https://{settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com/{image_path}"
```